# How should I make it possible to use MySql with INSERT/SELECT in jQuery/AJAX?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I'm trying to select data from one table and insert them in another without refreshing the page, but I feel a bit helpless right now.
How do I write something like this with jQuery/Ajax:

```
function myFunction($conn){
    $sql ="
        INSERT INTO MyTable (full_name, main_id, Status, Become)  
        SELECT mt.full_name, mt.main_id, true, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP    
        FROM MyOtherTable mt  
        WHERE NOT EXISTS 
          (SELECT main_id FROM MyTable mt_copy 
                WHERE mt_copy.main_id= mt.main_id)
         AND mt.main_id= ".$_POST['main_id']." ;
     ";
     $result = $conn->query($sql);
}
```

I can do the simple one like this:

#### php

```
  $conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', $user, $user, $user);

    $stmt = $conn->prepare(" INSERT INTO Posts(post_content, posted, customer_id) VALUES(?, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, '".$_SESSION['id']."')");
                                        
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $post_content);
                           
    $post_content = $_POST['post_content'];
    $stmt->execute();      
   #...
```

#### js

```
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $(".new-post").on('click', function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                let post_content=$("#post_content").val();
                $.ajax({
                    url:'insertPosts.php',
                    method:'POST',
                    data:{
                        post_content:post_content
                    },
                    success:function(r){
                       console.log("New post updated!!", r);
                       location.reload();
                    },
                    error:function(e){
                       console.log("Unexpected results", e);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
```

Comment: Are you trying to bypass PHP?

Comment: Something's not right here.  Your JavaScript layer shouldn't even _know_ that there is a database on the backend.  Instead, you should move your SQL query logic to your PHP script, and also use prepared statements.

Comment: The main purpose was to do the data transfer without reloading the page, and I found out that Ajax was the right tool.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, I tried a trick like this: ``` <?php
  echo"<script>";
       require "js/insertData.js";
     echo"</script>";
?>```